# Sails 1.0 (Waterline ORM) - MySQL attribute Date

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I want to store 2 data as **Date type** but as answer json I always get :
**"start": "2023-06-11T23:00:00.000Z"**, why this is happening?, into my MySQL database is saved like "2023-06-11".

That's my schema

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    title: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      columnType: 'varchar(50)'
    },
    start: {
      type: 'string',
      columnType: 'date',
      required: true
    },
    end: {
      type: 'string',
      columnType: 'date',
      allowNull: true
    }
  }
};

Thanks!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON has no standard for dates, so what you're getting in json is just the output of some default `toString` on your date.

On your server, waterline will treat the attribute as a date. But as soon as you send it to the client via json, it will be this string representation. Luckily, just passing this string into a `Date` contstructor will yield you the right javascript date object

```
var apiData = {
    title: 'hello',
    start: '2023-06-11T23:00:00.000Z'
};

var startDate = new Date(apiData.start); // this is a javascript Date object
```